# Check current language in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Would you please help me how to implement the below code in codeignitor ( In View Files )

```html
If(Language = "English "){
echo " 1 " ;
}
else{
Echo " 2 ";
|
```

Because I want to use the conditions to load some files for each language on the website such as CSS and other files.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: how do you set language?

Comment: You should have to store language in to session and than you can change the language as per selection of another language from home page the session will change and you can set the rest of all like css,html as per the language selection.

Answer (score 2):

```sh
If( $this->session->userdata('language') == "English "){
echo " 1 " ;
}
else{
Echo " 2 ";
|
```

it's return application current language

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html

Comment: I want to check the current language, not to return the default language.

Comment: try this it should retrun current language

Comment: @MakyDoz what u want to achive with this .?

Comment: In the website homepage, I want to view content only for Arabic language and if user choose another language, this content will disappear, so i want to make ( if condition ) on homepage template in the Views folder

Comment: have u load ur language helpers

Comment: Thank you so much, I fingered it out $this->session->userdata('language')